# When does this happen?

Tags: symbols

0>2 , 2>1 , 1>0

A common addition to this basic system is the addition of _________ and __________.

**What are the blanks**, which have English names as well as numerical values, find both. Note, a numerical value can correspond to more then one English name.

Hint:

> Use wikipedia for definition naming notation conventions when you are unsure about your model, not before.

Comment: Usually the question is asked as 0>2, 2>5, 5>0 (as the number indicates the number of fingers used)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this refers to

> Rock, paper, scissors.

We can think of the numbers as being

> 0 represents rock, 1 represents paper, and 2 represents scissors. This matches up more or less with the number of points sticking out in the shape your hand makes. Then 0>2, 2>1, 1>0 means that rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper, and paper beats rock.

The two common additions are

> Lizard and spock. Since Spock involves three appendages and lizard involves making a circle with your fingers, Spock is 3 and lizard is also 0. (See [here](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/Rock_Paper_Scissors_Lizard_Spock) for the rules and hand shapes of lizard and Spock.)

Comment: I think rock = 0, paper = 5, and scissor = 2 so the question should be : 2<0<5 ,  5<2<0, and 2<5<0